# Trying to export pandas dataframe as a .csv, but first column is being split into two

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which contains species data. When I try to convert it to a .csv file using to.csv(), it splits the species name into two columns
Expected output something like:

| Species | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Fraxinus excelsior | 10 |
| Fagus sylvatica | 7 |
| Fagus sylvatica | 18 |

Output:

| Species | Count |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fraxinus | excelsior | 10 |
| Fagus | sylvatica | 7 |
| Fagus | sylvatica | 18 |

How do I fix it so that it keeps the genus name and specific epithet in a single cell?

```py
df.to_csv("speciescount.csv")
```

Comment: sounds like an issue with the delimiter that's being used. To clarify, it looks like it's separating on spaces, not commas (comma separated values). It looks like they refer to this as `sep`, which you can provide via a param https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: @MattOestreich thanks for your response. I tried df.to_csv("speciescount.csv", sep = ",") but still giving the same output unfortunately

Comment: Can you give more information about your code ? I tried to create a dataframe, and export to csv. It works as normal.

Comment: I believe the csv file was created correctly. Check in the program you use to visualize csv (Excel, OpenOffice, etc) if the "separated by" radio buttons are marked "space" and "comma".

Comment: @washolive you're right! I was opening the .csv file in LibreOffice Calc, which I did not realise automatically selects all separator options when opening the file. Thank you :)